# Flow to track qualified contacts on the account page

Tags: visual-workflow, automation, recordtriggeredflow

We have a checkbox field (Qualified__c) on contacts that is checked if the contact is qualified. I want to create a flow to track the number of qualified contacts per account in a field called Qualified_Contacts__c.

My current record-triggered flow recognizes when the box is checked but never counts higher than one. Even if an account has several qualified contacts.

My flow is on the Contact object > when a record is created or updated > where Qualified__c is changed to equal True

[image]

The assignment *should* increment by one every time we check the qualified box:[image]

And then I have an update records action which should set the Qualified Contacts field on accounts equal to whatever variable was incremented to:[image]

However, this number never goes higher than one. What am I doing wrong? I cannot use anything other than a flow for this task.

Comment: How are you initializing `VarnCount`?

Answer (score 1):

From what you've shown, you're not initializing the `VarnCount` variable.

If you're going to increment it, you need to query it from the Account object first.

ie. Add a step before the assignment that queries the Account to get the current value, increment it, then update the Account